# Java Program cant find symbol

Tags: java

```
public class PlaneDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayQueue<Plane> q = new ArrayQueue<Plane>();
        Plane p1 = new Plane("Aircraft 1", 3);
        Plane p2 = new Plane("Aircraft 2", 1);
        Plane p3 = new Plane("Aircraft 3", 2);

        q.addQueue(p1);
        q.addQueue(p2);
        q.addQueue(p3);

        while(!q.isEmptyQueue())
        {
            System.out.println("Vehicle: ");
            System.out.println(q.front());
            q.deleteQueue();
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> cannot find symbol
>       q.addQueue(p1);
>        ^
>   symbol:   method addQueue(Plane)
>   location: variable q of type ArrayQueue<Plane>
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>       q.addQueue(p2);
>        ^
>   symbol:   method addQueue(Plane)
>   location: variable q of type ArrayQueue<Plane>
> ```

Im like panicking this is due soon and I can't figure out what I did wrong.

```
    public class ArrayQueue<T>
{
    private int maxQueueSize;
    private int count;
    private int queueFront;
    private int queueRear;
    private T[] list;

    public ArrayQueue()
    {
        maxQueueSize = 100;
        queueFront = 0;
        queueRear = maxQueueSize - 1;
        count = 0;
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxQueueSize];
    }

    public ArrayQueue(int queueSize)
    {
        if(queueSize <= 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Array size must be a positive number. Creating array at default size of 100.");
            maxQueueSize = 100;
        }
        else
            maxQueueSize = queueSize;

        queueFront = 0;
        queueRear = maxQueueSize - 1;
        count = 0;
        list = (T[]) new Object[maxQueueSize];
    }

    public void initializeQueue()
    {
        for(int i = queueFront; i < queueRear; i = (i + 1) % maxQueueSize)
        list[i] = null;

        queueFront = 0;
        queueRear = maxQueueSize - 1;
        count = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmptyQueue()
    {
        return(count == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFullQueue()
    {
        return(count == maxQueueSize);
    }

    public T peek() //throws QueueUnderflowException
    {
        /*if(isEmptyQueue())
            throw new QueueUnderflowException();*/

        return (T) list[queueFront];
    }

    /*public T back() throws QueueOverflowException
    {
        if(isFullQueue())
            throw new QueueUnderflowException();
        return (T) list[queueRear];
    }
*/
    public void enqueue(T queueElement) throws QueueOverflowException
    {
        if(isFullQueue())
            throw new QueueOverflowException();

        queueRear = (queueRear + 1) % maxQueueSize;
        count++;
        list[queueRear] = queueElement;
    }

    public void dequeue() throws QueueUnderflowException
    {
        if(isEmptyQueue())
            throw new QueueUnderflowException();

        count--;
        list[queueFront] = null;

        queueFront = (queueFront + 1) % maxQueueSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the javadoc of `ArrayQueue` say?

Comment: can you import ArrayQueue?

Comment: Is ArrayQueue a class you wrote? Double check the method name

Comment: Yes ArrayQueue is a class i wrote i just posted it

Comment: You need to call enqueue not addQueue

Comment: Are you using an IDE? That would make you see your error before you compile the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
q.addQueue(p1);
q.addQueue(p2);
        q.addQueue(p3);
```

For this `q.enqueue(p1); etc` because is the only,method you have to add an element to the class

```
public void enqueue(T queueElement) throws QueueOverflowException
    {
```